# How to properly convert currency in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, lambda

I have been working on a currency convert on VS in c# , my current challenging is how to properly convert Dollar to Frank ,Euro to Pound  Sterling to Frank, but when i run the programing everything seems working fine until i enter the amount to be converted in Dollar it works and when i try with the other currencies just doesn't show any result or raise any exception. below is my program, I tried searching for similar challenges but couldn't find one that suit my case ! I am very new to the C# language and community, Maybe it might not be a very smart question but i really do need help !

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int ;
            double val,frank;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your Choice :\n 1- Dollar to Frank \n 2- Euro to Frank \n 3- Sterling to Frank ");
            choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 
             (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    Double dollar;
                    Console.Write("Enter the Dollar Amount :");
                    dollar = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("Enter the Dollar Value :");
                    val = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    frank = dollar * val;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Dollar Equals {1} Frank", dollar, frank);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Double Euro;
                    Console.Write("Enter the Euro Amount :");
                    Euro  Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("Enter the Euro Value :");
                    val = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    frank = Euro * val;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Euro Equals {1} Frank", Euro, frank);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Double sterling;
                    Console.Write("Enter the Sterling Amount :");
                    Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("Enter the Sterling Value :");
                    val = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    frank = sterling * val;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Sterling Equals {1} Frank", sterling, frank);
                    break;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code doesnt compile, which is a good place to start with investigating the problem. `int;` on the first line. A missing `switch` statement before `(choice)` plus a [whole load of other mistakes the compiler will tell you about](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YWzSKH) in the error or output windows of your favourite IDE

Comment: Also, don't use `double` for currency amounts. Always use `decimal`.

Comment: What is a "Frank Euro" and what is a "Frank Sterling"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try to tackle this in a more generic way and with less repetition.

```
public static void Main()
{
    decimal EnterDecimal(string message, bool zero_allowed)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            if (decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out decimal value))
                if (zero_allowed || value != 0m)
                    return value;
        }
    }

    string EnterCurrency(string message)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            string currency = Console.ReadLine().ToUpperInvariant();
            if (currency.Length == 3)
                return currency;
        }
    }

    string currency_from = EnterCurrency("Enter From Currency");
    string currency_to = EnterCurrency("Enter To Currency");
    decimal rate = EnterDecimal($"Enter exchange rate from {currency_from} to {currency_to}", false);
    decimal amount_from = EnterDecimal($"Enter the amount of {currency_from} to convert", true);
    decimal amount_to = amount_from * rate;
    Console.WriteLine($"{amount_from} {currency_from} equals {amount_to} {currency_to}");
}
```

A typical run of this code might be:

```
Enter From Currency
AUD
Enter To Currency
USD
Enter exchange rate from AUD to USD
0.7
Enter the amount of AUD to convert
100
100 AUD equals 70.0 USD
```